# Image popup while hovering over text. And simultaneous text color change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a paragraph where I want to add some picture while a user hovers over the certain word. I can do it with CSS and jquery. But it does not create the popup. Just it reformats the text and shows the picture. And it does not also change the color. How can I do it with class or ID? I am not CS major. Just a novice learner. Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will help you if you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this free [project](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2016/11/01/media-pop-up-effect/) from tympanus. Or it is hard for you, you can show image when you hover it with jQuery

```
$(TEXT).hover(function(){
   $(IMAGE).fadeIn();
})
```